# ZAPIER CODE STEP HTTP REQUEST

Tags: ibm-watson, zapier

I need generate the following request in zapier with a code step. I use webhook function but for some reason the answer is a separated comma value and i need the full json. I try in postman and works perfect. But i dont unterstand so fine how i can do with code. I use postman to format the code in nodejs the code run but dont geck back anything. Somebody can help so fin the problem? thans so much. (i´m a basic user for that reason i dont untersant all)

The request:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13&consumption_preferences=false&raw_scores=true' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'accept-language: es' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic here is the token' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
```

```js
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "gateway.watsonplatform.net",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/personality-insights/api/v3/profile?version=2017-10-13&consumption_preferences=false&raw_scores=false",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Basic HEREISTHETOKEN==",
    "accept-language": "es",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ contentItems: 
   [ { content: 'Wow, I liked @TheRock before, nowLa evaluada aseguró que no adulteró, falsificó u omitió intencionalmente alguna información en su solicitud de empleo, dice que toda la información suministrada en este proceso de selección es completamente legal y en cualquier momento se puede validar.   I really SEE how special he is. The daughterIndicó que consume licor solo en ocasiones especiales, las bebidas que acostumbra a consumir son: cerveza, teniendo un consumo máximo por ocasión de 5 cervezas. Aseguró no haber tenido dependencia de las sustancias alcohólicas e indicó no tener antecedentes de alcoholismo en la familia. Agregó no haber tenido incumplimientos o problemas laborales a causa del licor. story was IT for me. So great! #MasterClass So great! #MasterClasWow, I liked @TheRock before, nowLa evaluada aseguró que no adulteró, falsificó u omitió intencionalmente alguna información en su solicitud de empleo, dice que toda la información suministrada en este proceso de selección es completamente legal y en cualquier momento se puede validar.   I really SEE how special he is. The daughterIndicó que consume licor solo en ocasiones especiales, las bebidas que acostumbra a consumir son: cerveza, teniendo un consumo máximo por ocasión de 5 cervezas. Aseguró no haber tenido dependencia de las sustancias alcohólicas e indicó no tener antecedentes de alcoholismo en la familia. Agregó no haber tenido incumplimientos o problemas laborales a causa del licor. story was IT for me. So great! #MasterClasss',
       contenttype: 'text/plain',
       created: 1447639154000,
       id: '666073008692314113',
       language: 'es' } ] }));
req.end();
  return {DATA: http.text};
```

Comment: that isn't a runnable code snippet

Comment: Have you seen the zapier example of an API call? `fetch` is available and will greatly simplify your code: https://zapier.com/help/code/#weather-json-api-call